# Network setup on AWS for NFS

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, nfs, amazon-vpc

I have a number of servers which all need external IP addresses, as they provide different services and need to be invidually accessible:

```
server1.mydomain.com > 1.2.3.4
server2.mydomain.com > 2.3.4.5
server3.mydomain.com > 3.4.5.6
...
serverN.mydomain.com > n.n.n.n
```

Shared among these servers is a NFS share on a server called `files.mydomain`.

Basically, I want to have my public servers be able to privately access `files.mydomain` over an intranet (secure) rather than over the internet (totally not secure). How can I do this? All servers need to be publicly accessible to SSH and other services, but NFS specifically needs to be done over a local network within the Amazon cloud privately. I was thinking of using a VPC, but I'm not sure how to make this happen to keep the servers externally accessible while still keeping internal networking available between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely should use a VPC for this. All of your instances will get a private IP inside the VPC, and then for those that need public IP addresses, either associate an EIP with them or set up port forwarding from a NAT instance.

With regards to NFS traffic, create a Security Group that allows traffic on NFS ports from group members, and add that group to each of your instances.

Comment: Do I need multiple subnets, or can all this be managed in a single subnet?

Comment: You don't need multiple subnets for this.